# Wiring left and right channels together coming out of MP3 player module

Tags: amplifier, sound, dfplayer

I have a DFPlayer MP3 module and i'd like to use the dac_l and dac_r outputs to connect to an amplifier. However, the amplifier is mono and i'd like to hear both channels coming out of the speaker.

Could i connect the dac_r and dac_l lines together to get mono audio to connect to the amplifier? Or will it kill the DFPlayer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know what kind of output stage the DAC output pins have, so it is not known if they can be directly shorted together or not.

Simply downmix the output to mono by connecting them together via resistors, two 4.7 kohm resistors should work fine so they are not directly shorted together.